# What strategies can I take to enable me to release multiple applications from the same code base?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an app, which be be a game/quiz type application for testing a users ability at a given subject, such as a Spanish tester. The user will download the app and it will be pre-loaded with a bunch of quizes/flashcards etc.

The actual source code for this application will be fairly independant of the subject, therefore I hope to just switch out the database should I wish to create a similar application for a different topic, such as a German tester.

As the code source would be practically the same, having the same package structures and such, does this prevent me from deploying both of these to the market?

What would I need to maintain in order to publish multiple applications from essentially the same source base?

Thanks

Comment: what about creating "Core Quiz Game"(CQG) as free with some quiz(ContentProvider) ... and sell app, which don't have LAUNCHER activity but they are new ContentProvider(only resources/question in db) for CQG and then CQG iterate installed pakages and search for your's ContentProviders and user can select between quizzes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842798/how-do-you-realise-two-versions-of-an-app-on-the-market/4842909#4842909) previous question which covers the same ground.

Answer (score 0):

Off topic:

I have in mind you to do localization of the application and based of language selection load cards, quizes etc in that language, instead of deploying new application. And you'll have the quality over quantity.

On topic:
I don't know if Market allows deploying same packaged several times.

Comment: No, it does not. But you can use the techniques outlined in the answer I linked to to create multiple different applications, with different packages, from a single code base.

Comment: How does Market check for dupe? If it does by package name/app name then the code can be reused with different name, right?

Comment: Yes - that's exactly how it does it. The trick is how to arrange for a single codebase to be compiled with different manifests (which is what's described in the answer I linked to).